# Select em dois campos de uma tabela

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner

Olá, estou passando por um problema e gostaria de pedir ajuda de vocês. É o seguinte:

Estou integrando um sistema PHP ao plugin Woocommerce do Wordpress e necessito requisitar alguns produtos do banco de dados, até ai tudo bem. O problema se incia ao buscar o produto na tabela. Ela está assim

```
Order id              meta_key           value
1                     2                  3
2                     2                  87
3                     3                  45
```

Eu preciso selecionar o id 1 que contem o valor 3 desde que o id 2 contenha o valor 87. Como faço isso? Estou completamente perdido

Comment: coloque a estrutura das tabelas, dados de amostragem e de preferência, utilize o SQLFiddle

Comment: Qual a relação do ID 1 com o ID 2 ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis nenhuma, bem vindo ao **weirdpress**

Comment: Então essa meta_key não tem relação nenhuma? E quais são suas entradas, 3 e 87 mesmo?

Comment: Na verdade eu quero pegar o valor 3 que tem o meta_key de valor 2, ou seja, eu vou pegar o valor 3 que no caso é o correspondente de 87 que é o id. Imaginem assim, o 3 é o valor da camiseta que eu irei vender na loja e 87 é o id do produto, por isso necessito de pegar o valor do produto 87 usando a mesma chave que é comum nos dois, que no caso é o numero 2